# Explanation of specific list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, evaluation

I've a question regarding list comprehension

```
[(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3], let z = x+y, odd z]
```

Why does this evaluate to:

```
[(1,2),(2,3)]
```

?

Where is the z going?

Thanks

Comment: `[(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3]]` evaluates to something different. Try it..

Comment: `z` is used in the predicate `odd z`, so this will only return pairs whose sum is odd.

Comment: But 2 isn't odd... I need some more explanation please. It hurts in my brain ^^

Comment: `z` is the sum of `x` and `y` i.e. the sum of the two elements in the pair. `1+2` is odd and `2+3` is also odd.

Comment: Ahh now I get it. (1,1) no, (1,2) yes, (1,3) no, (2,2) no, (2,3) yes which leads to [(1,2),(2,3)] Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your predicate is "z = x + y for all z odd". If you "unroll" the flow:

z = predicate, and y(x) so for:

```
x = 1,2
y (1) = 1,2,3
y (2) = 2,3
```

Based on the combination of the values filtered by the predicate:

```
x+y <= filter(z)

1+1 = 2 NO
1+2 = 3 OK
1+3 = 4 NO

2+2 = 4 NO
2+3 = 5 OK
```

so the ok answers are for x = 1 and y = 2 and x = 2 and y =3 => `[(1,2), (2,3)]`

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks for your effort!